# How to get position of item in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android

In my application I want create custom calendar with `RecyclerView` and for this I write below codes. 
I want set **black** color for today and next days and set **gray** color for previous days. 
I can know which day is today, but I don't know how can I get today's position in adapter for set gray color! 
**My Adapter color:**

```
class DaysAdapter constructor(val context: Context, private val items: MutableList<DayEntity>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DaysAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val TYPE_HEADER = 0
    private val TYPE_DAY = 1
    private var firstDayDayOfWeek = 0
    private var totalDays = 0

    init {
        firstDayDayOfWeek = items[0].dayOfWeek
        totalDays = items.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_day_new, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = 7 * 7

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
            TYPE_HEADER
        } else {
            TYPE_DAY
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(position)

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val dayTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayTxt) as TextView

        //Bind data
        fun bind(pos: Int) {
            var position = pos
            position += 6 - (position % 7) * 2

            if (totalDays < position - 6 - firstDayDayOfWeek) {
                return
            } else {
                //Day
                if (!isPositionHeader(position)) {
                    if (position - 7 - firstDayDayOfWeek >= 0) {
                        val day = items[position - 7 - firstDayDayOfWeek]
                        dayTxt.isVisible = true
                        dayTxt.text = day.num
                        items[position].dayOfWeek
                        //Today
                        if (position < day.isToday) {
                            dayTxt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray))
                        } else {
                            dayTxt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
                        }
                    } else {
                        dayTxt.isVisible = false
                    }
                } else {
                    //Header
                    dayTxt.text = Constants.FIRST_CHAR_OF_DAYS_OF_WEEK_NAME[position]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isPositionHeader(position: Int) = position < 7
}
```

`day.isToday` is **boolean** and but I don't how can I completed this code `if (position < day.isToday)` for set gray color. 
`day.isToday` is **Boolean** and I can't used it in `if (position < day.isToday)` .

`day.isToday` is **Boolean** and I can't used it in `if (position < day.isToday)` . 
How can I it?

Comment: Why do you need to check the position? You can use the current item you're binding from `items[position]` and check if that day is `today`. Something like `if (items[position].isToday)`. Would that work?

Comment: @PedroOliveira Thanks my firne, this code `(items[position].isToday)` just set color for today. I want Today and next days have black and previous days have gray. for example : today is **19** .  from **19** to **30** are black color and from **1** to **18** are gray color. how can I it?

Comment: @Dr.KeyOk
 when create your item list to give to the adapter, add also the color property to DayEntity.
so you don,t need to have any logic on adapter for setting the color, but have the 'logic' mapped on object, so on adapter just execute it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
You can use the Calendar class to get the current date and then compare it with the date of the days that you want to color. Based on the comparison you can set the color of the days.

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

if (dayOfMonth < currentDay) {
// Previous days
textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
} else {
// Today and next days
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
 }
```

**OLD**
you can try this where you are comparing position with day.IsToday in bind() method just simply try the below code

```
 inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val dayTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayTxt) as TextView

    //Bind data
    fun bind(pos: Int) {
        var position = pos
        position += 6 - (position % 7) * 2

        if (totalDays < position - 6 - firstDayDayOfWeek) {
            return
        } else {
            //Day
            if (!isPositionHeader(position)) {
                if (position - 7 - firstDayDayOfWeek >= 0) {
                    val day = items[position - 7 - firstDayDayOfWeek]
                    dayTxt.isVisible = true
                    dayTxt.text = day.num
                    items[position].dayOfWeek
                    //Today
                    if (items[position].isToday) {
                        dayTxt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray))
                    } else {
                        dayTxt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
                    }
                } else {
                    dayTxt.isVisible = false
                }
            } else {
                //Header
                dayTxt.text = 
        Constants.FIRST_CHAR_OF_DAYS_OF_WEEK_NAME[position]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code (items[position].isToday) just set color for today. I want Today and next days have black and previous days have gray. for example : today is 19 . from 19 to 30 are black color and from 1 to 18 are gray color. how can I it?

Comment: you can check again my answer which I have updated

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming

> items[position].isToday

this function will identify your date is today or not.

Now simply get today position and store it some where globally like

```
Int todayPosition=-1 // note take it globally, where it will not over-right every time.  

if(items[position].isToday){
   todayPosition=position 
}
```

Now you have to just compare position

```
if(position==todayPosition){
//Today colour
}else if(position <todayPosition){
//Past colour
}else{
//Future colour
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks my friend, but why show me such as this? https://freeimage.host/i/HcJo98x . today is 29 (in my region), but just change color to 24! why not set this to 1 ?